# Why would the addition of parentheses in SQL query cause the results to change?

Tags: sql, parentheses

When I execute the following query, even though there are 11 records that match, none are returned as written.  However, if I remove the parentheses on lines 6 and 9, all 11 records are returned as expected.

```
1  select obj_id, obj_title, UI_DISPLAYNAME
2  from PITS_OBJECT 
3  LEFT OUTER JOIN ui_displayname_view ON obj_create_ui_id = UI_ID  
4  where
5  /* w/ parens, no results, w/o parens, expected results */
6  (
7     Upper( UI_DISPLAYNAME ) LIKE Upper( '%smith%' )  
8     OR Upper( OBJ_TITLE ) LIKE Upper( '%smith%' ) 
9  )
10 /* end w/ parents, no results.... */
11 AND OBJ_ID IN (select obj_id from PITS_OBJECT where 
12     (UPPER( OBJ_TITLE ) LIKE UPPER( '%smith%' )) 
13     AND obj_id in( select sa_obj_id as obj_id from security_access 
14         where sa_type_id = 494 
15         and sa_usrgrp_id = 35
16         and sa_usrgrp_type_id = 230 
17         union 
18         select sa_obj_id from security_access 
19         where sa_type_id = 494 
20         and sa_usrgrp_type_id = 231 
21         and sa_usrgrp_id in ( select ug_gi_id from user_group where ug_ui_id = 35)) )
```

Why would this matter?  Wouldn't the OR statement mean that one or the other must be true?  What am I missing here?

Comment: +1 for a good post. The addition of the line numbers to make it easy to describe where you were having the issue was a nice touch.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Three words: order of operations. It's like you learned in math, certain operators take precedence over others (like multiplying comes before adding) unless you use parentheses to force it your way. In this case, `AND` has a higher precedence than `OR`.

Without adding in your own parentheses, your `WHERE` clause gets evaluated like this:

```
Upper( UI_DISPLAYNAME ) LIKE Upper( '%smith%' )
OR 
(Upper( OBJ_TITLE ) LIKE Upper( '%smith%' ) 
    AND OBJ_ID IN (select obj_id from PITS_OBJECT where 
    ...)
```

But when you manually add in those parentheses, you're forcing the `OR` to be evaluated first.

```
(Upper( UI_DISPLAYNAME ) LIKE Upper( '%smith%' )
    OR Upper( OBJ_TITLE ) LIKE Upper( '%smith%' ))
AND OBJ_ID IN (select obj_id from PITS_OBJECT where 
...
```

**Edit:** I should directly answer your question about why you're getting back more data. The reason is because, without the parentheses, the engine will short-circuit its check if it finds that line 7 is true. In other words, it will include all records where `Upper( UI_DISPLAYNAME ) LIKE Upper( '%smith%' )`, regardless of the other criteria.

When you add in those parentheses, the logic changes. It will include records where `Upper( UI_DISPLAYNAME ) LIKE Upper( '%smith%' ) OR Upper( OBJ_TITLE ) LIKE Upper( '%smith%' )`, and then it checks that the record ALSO satisfies the inner select that starts on line 12. Those extra records don't show up because they're not meeting the criteria of that inner select.

Comment: Thanks, that also explains it why, when I reversed the order of the the columns (lines 7 and 8), I got nothing regardless of whether there were parens or not.  The only TRUE value was the UI_DISPLAYNAME containing '%smith%'; neither OBJ_TITLE or the subselect contained matching records.

Comment: Experimentation is definitely the best way to figure out what's going on with SQL queries. Just start adding, subtracting, and flip-flopping clauses until you figure out what's going on :)

Answer (score 16):

Your where clause is currently analogous to the following:

```
(A || B) && C && D
```

Without parenthesis, it is as follows

```
A || B && C && D
```

Which is equivalent to

```
A || (B && (C && D))
```

Comment: There's actually only an `A`, `B`, and `C`. The `D` you're seeing is actually part of an inner select that starts on line 12. It's hard to tell because of the way the SQL is formatted. You're still essentially right, though.

Answer (score 2):

It has to do with the precedence of `AND` and `OR` operators. `AND` has higher precedence.
http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/conditions001.htm#i1034834

Answer (score 0):

Because you have changed your where statement to always return records where
`Upper( OBJ_TITLE ) LIKE Upper( '%smith%' )` is true, regardless of your next AND

Comment: To help Sam find it, it's in line 12. Nice catch, BTW. +1

Comment: Line 12 is part of an inner select, I don't see how it is related to the OP's question.

Comment: It is not part of an inner select. Removing the () at lines 6 and 9 will cause records to be returned whenever Upper( OBJ_TITLE ) LIKE Upper( '%smith%' ) is true, I would appreciate it if you removed your down vote......

Comment: @Maess I'm sorry but you're wrong. Look at line 11: `AND OBJ_ID IN (select ...` -- that inner select continues onto line 12, and in fact it goes all the way to the very end (because there is another inner select nested inside that, and then _another_ inner select nested inside that! There's a 4-level deep inner select).

Comment: The evaluation of that AND has no effect if the previous OR is true because of the elimination of the ().  The inner select does not start until line 11.  Regardless of how the inner select evaluates, the OR statement, if evaluated to true, trumps.  I think you missread the question, he is asking why it returns results when he removes the ().

Comment: You're still mistaken. What's causing him to get more data back without the parentheses is that the first clause, `Upper( UI_DISPLAYNAME ) LIKE Upper( '%smith%' )`, is evaluating to true and short-circuiting. The clause you're referring to can only short-circuit the `where` if it _doesn't_ find data. Again, the `and` has to be evaluated first before its results become part of the `or`. In order words, to determine record inclusion without the parentheses the engine is saying `if line 7 is true or if (line 8 and lines 9+ are true)`. So he's getting back records where line 7 is true.

Answer (score 0):

This is basic order of operations. The parentheses mean that everything is tested before anything else is tested. The value returned after evaluating the items in the parentheses will then be used to evaluate the rest. Since AND takes precedence over OR, the parentheses make SQL evaluate the ORs first.